# Retrofit returning internal server error status 500

Tags: android, json, http-post, retrofit2

I am implementing retrofit in my android application for user login. The input type is Json. I have 500 internal server error, every time when i try to send POST request via Retrofit.

```
   ApiInterface apiInterface=AppController.GetRetrofitObject().create(ApiInterface.class);
        // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
        try {
            JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                paramObject.put(ApiName.USERNAME, username);
                paramObject.put(ApiName.PASSWORD, password);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG,paramObject.toString());
            Call<Login> call = apiInterface.getLoginDetails(paramObject.toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Login> call, @NonNull Response<Login> response) {
                    String message = response.message();
                    int status = response.code();

                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(status));
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Every time i am getting status as 500. But i am getting the response in POSTMAN.My Interface class is

```
  public interface ApiInterface {

@POST(ApiName.LOGIN)
Call<Login> getLoginDetails(@Body String body);
}
```

[image: Postman screen shot]

Comment: print url in api call function

Answer (score 0):

Change `String body` to be Java pojo.  for example : `User`

```
@POST(ApiName.LOGIN)
Call<Login> getLoginDetails(@Body User body);
}
```

.......

```
class User {

private String username;
private String password;

public User() {}

public User(String username, String password) {
   this.username = username;
   this.password = password;
}

// setter + getter//

}
```

then call :

```
....

User user = new User(username, password);
Call<Login> call = apiInterface.getLoginDetails(user);

....
```